# How to use the IsWindowsXPOrGreater function correctly?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2013

**Update**

I have re-wrote the original question as the previous text was more of a story than describing my real problem:

We have a set of applications that target Windows XP up to Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2008 & 2012 (32-bit/64-bit version support too).  Previously we did nothing in code to make sure you were running on these platforms.

We made a change to use the `IsWindowsXPOrGreater` function call when creating our set of Windows API wrapper classes.  If this call returns false we throw an exception, that will be caught and cause an error message to display.

However, the error message is created by jumping through a set of Windows API calls.  According to MSDN most of the calls require Windows 2000 or later, although a few are Windows XP or later.

After implementing the unit tests and mod I developed doubts that the code will actually run if we actually ran the software on anything prior to Windows XP - because either the `IsWindowsXPOrGreater` function requires Windows 2000 or later or the error message module will fail on their calls to the Windows API.

I have shown my colleagues that if I force `IsWindowsXPOrGreater` to give a false return, an exception is raised but we end up in an endless loop because our error message module raises another instance of the exception, which we pick up again to try to use the Windows API and so on.

**Question**

If `IsWindowsXPOrGreater` returns false which Windows API calls are safe to use on any 32-bit installation of a Windows operating system?

MSDN seems to show a minimum of Windows 2000 or Windows XP for most Windows API functions.  Is there any documentation for the earlier versions of User32.dll, Kernel32.dll etc?

**My Current Workaround**

We have since changed our code to catch a new `LowerThanWindowsXPException` - which will use a variant wrapper for `MessageBox` to display a simple message before terminating the app.  This variant does not check the windows version, and is based on some legacy Visual Basic code we have lying around.  This worked on Windows 95 although we have no way of checking that now.

In the future we will be using `IsWindows7OrGreater` for additional Windows API calls and in these cases we will raise a `LowerThanWindows7Exception` - which we can catch and treat differently (such as use our Windows XP API calls to display an error message or fall back on some alternative functionality).

Comment: This is way too much text, but if anyone is using something earlier than Windows XP and you don't know about it, you probably shouldn't care about them.

Comment: I've read this twice and I still cannot work out what you are asking.

Comment: If no used will be running on a pre-XP system then why are you checking for that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I have completely re-worded this to make it clear, or at least less of a story

Comment: Do you want a full list of APIs that are available on NT4 and Win2k?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes, an online source so I can check the function signatures.  Its odd to see MSDN list functions as Windows 2000 or later if they are available on Windows 95, for example.

Comment: There is no such list online. You need MSDN DVDs from circa 2000.

Comment: I've been told that a Windows API text file appears in the VB6.0 CD.  I believe I found a copy of this text file here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=12427 - this should be a sufficient source for our review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [/DELAYLOAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx) when you link so that your application will only attempt to load DLLs when you call a function from that DLL.

From there, you can use older functions to print out an error message if a new-enough version of Windows isn't available. Just for one obvious example, `MessageBox` has been around since the 16-bit Windows days. Using it, any 32-bit Windows system back to Windows 95 and/or Windows NT 3.1 will print out your error message without a problem. LoadString is another that's been around since the dawn of time, so using it won't cause a problem with older versions of Windows either.

Basically, the only way it's not going to work is if they run it on a pure 16-bit Windows system (Windows 3.1 or earlier) without Win32s installed, in which case they'll just get a message saying Windows can't load the executable. If there's anybody still running 16-bit Windows, they're probably pretty accustomed to seeing that by now.

Comment: We have no problem with the program failing if any of the *32.dlls fail to load.  Your suggestion for `MessageBox` was helpful, and we able to dig out some legacy code in VB to see how it was used on a Windows 95 machine.